# Javascript minifier removes function

Tags: javascript, web-essentials

I have a JS file that I am trying to minify but it is having some trouble. Here is the file:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
function DisplayMessage(message, iserror) {
    var htmlclass = iserror ? "error" : "success";

    $('div.response-message').empty()
        .append(message)
        .addClass(htmlclass);

    $('div.response-message').animate({
        top: "-1px"
    }, 1000, function () {
        alert("donee");
    });
}

$('.account-overlay-link > a.link').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.account-overlay.background').removeClass("hide");
});

$('.account-overlay > .area > .close').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.account-overlay.background').addClass("hide");
});
});
```

As you can see I have a regular javascript function at the top and two jQuery event handlers below. When I save the file to minify, the minified file contains the two jQuery handlers but the function is nowhere to be seen.

Strangely, if I remove the two jQuery blocks but leave the function in, the file still minifies, but it is blank (apart from the `(document).ready`) as if the function does not exist.

I have tried recreating the file, restarting Visual Studios, but nothing is working...

Answer (score 4):

Your function is not called by any code inside the "ready" handler function, so it's being eliminated as dead code.  Nothing from outside the handler would be able to call it anyway.

If you want the function to be a globally-visible symbol, you'll have to explicitly assign it to a property of the `window` object:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
function DisplayMessage(message, iserror) {
    var htmlclass = iserror ? "error" : "success";

    $('div.response-message').empty()
        .append(message)
        .addClass(htmlclass);

    $('div.response-message').animate({
        top: "-1px"
    }, 1000, function () {
        alert("donee");
    });
}
window.DisplayMessage = DisplayMessage;
```

If you do that, the minifier won't remove it.

Comment: Doing the window.DisplayMessage doesn't change anything unfortunately

Comment: @Frayt well what minifier are you using? Personally I would consider it a bug if copying a function reference to a `window` property didn't make it "live", but your minifier may require that you explicitly tell it (via a special comment or something) that a function shouldn't be treated as dead code.

Comment: @Frayt also note that `window.DisplayMessage = DisplayMessage;` needs to be **outside** the function, not inside.

Comment: The one included with the Web Essentials plugin

Comment: @Frayt as an experiment, this may work: `$("dummy").on("nothing", "*", DisplayMessage);` - if the minimizer didn't remove your other jQuery code, it should leave that alone too *and* it shouldn't remove the function. (However, the function still won't be visible outside the "ready" handler unless you set it up as a `window` property also.)

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to keep in mind is that some minifiers cannot deal with "special" keywords...

Consider to check your Code if it contains "fancy" stuff like

- **let, const**
- special loops like **for(var a of myData)**
- special checks such as if("MyProperty" in myObject)

At least in my case, this was the real problem